# Parse ODATA URL to read ID value before preparing entityset

Tags: java, odata

I'm new to ODATA. The examples given in https://olingo.apache.org builds the entityset first and then out of it, it fetches one entity based on the ID passed in the URL. What i need is how to read the entity id from the URL and then build the entity.

Ex: In the request /car.srv/Cars(5), read 5 in the Servlet and then build the entity.

Can someone help me how to do it in Java?